# Fast way to initialize child Kotlin class with parent class' instance properties

Tags: inheritance, intellij-idea, kotlin

I use Java library that defines a JSON model class named `A`. This class contains a lot of properties, e. g., 26 `String` properties named from `a` to `z` and does not have a constructor for them.

I'd like to extend this class in Kotlin with a new JSON property, `lateinit var aa: String` (derived class will be `B`), and to have a fast way to create an instance of `B` by copying properties of existing `A` instance.

I can serialize `A` and deserialize the resultant JSON to `B`. Are there any other fast solutions to do this without serializing/deserializing, e.g. by using any Kotin/Java methods or Intellij IDEA facilities?

Comment: This screams "composition over inheritance"..

Comment: You'd have to provide it in your constructor and assign each field manually.

Comment: If you can switch from a Java library to a Kotlin Data Class, you get a built in copy method.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you only have 1 constructor, here you go:

```
inline fun <reified D> convert(c: Any) : D {
    val list = mutableListOf<Any>()
    c::class.java.declaredFields.forEach {
        it.isAccessible = true
        list.add(it.get(c) as String)
        it.isAccessible = false
    }

    val constructor = D::class.java.declaredConstructors[0]
    return constructor.newInstance(*list.toTypedArray()) as D
}
```

Full use:

```
package com.erezbiox1

fun main(args: Array<String>){

    val A = A("Hey", "Hello")
    val B = convert<B>(A)
    B.print()

}

inline fun <reified D> convert(c: Any) : D {
    val list = mutableListOf<Any>()
    c::class.java.declaredFields.forEach {
        it.isAccessible = true
        list.add(it.get(c) as String)
        it.isAccessible = false
    }

    val constructor = D::class.java.declaredConstructors[0]
    return constructor.newInstance(*list.toTypedArray()) as D
}

class A(val a: String, val b: String){
    fun print(){
        println("Value is: $a, $b")
    }
}

class B(val a: String, val b: String) {
    fun print(){
        println("Value is: $a, $b")
    }
}
```